# Rails properly pass in id through form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I just need some clarity of thought on this one. I've got a Photos show page where a user can click "Like" to create a new `like` record for a particular `photo`.

On my photos show.html page I have the following form:

```
<%= form_for :like, :url => likes_path do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:photo_id, @photo.id) %>
  <%= f.submit "Like" %>
<% end %>
```

When I click the form I get a message that it "Couldn't find a Photo without an ID":

```
Started POST "/likes" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Feb 25 16:43:21 -0500 2012
Processing by LikesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Like", "authenticity_token"=>"cQnuAHb/f6Sgo3aB5xPKErx3joQTV+DHGs0w9vi13vM=", "utf8"=>"\342\234\223", "photo_id"=>"47"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 68ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Photo without an ID):
  app/controllers/likes_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

Not sure why when it seems to be passing in the photo_id correctly, no?
Here's a look at my `likes_controller`:

```
def create
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  @like = Like.new(:photo_id => :photo_id, :user_id => current_user.id)
end
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with `Photo.find(params[:photo_id])`.

The error message says that you called `Photo.find`with a `nil` parameter, e.g. there is no parameter `id` in the request.